# How to put element from an aray in an input

Tags: reactjs

I am coding an application and the purpose of it is to show two tables: one with elements from an array and the others one with input that are suggesting elements from an another array.

I don't know how to put my data from OldData.json into my input suggestion which is -> const RecentResearches

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import NewData from '../../api/data/cities.json'
import OldData from '../../api/data/historical.json'
import Pagination from './Pagination.js'
import SuggestionInputSearch from 'suggestion-react-input-search';

react class NewDataTable extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            NewData: NewData,
            pageOfItems: []
        };
        this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    }

    onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
        // update state with new page of items
        this.setState({ pageOfItems: pageOfItems });
    }

    render() {
        const recentSearches = [{OldData.name}];

        return (
            <div>
                <nav><Pagination items={this.state.NewData} onChangePage={this.onChangePage} /></nav>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>New Data</th>
                            <th>Old Data</th>
                        </tr>

                        {this.state.pageOfItems.map(item =>
                            <tr key={item.id}><td key={item.id}>{item.name}</td>
                            <td><SuggestionInputSearch
                                recentSearches={recentSearches}
                            /></td></tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

OldData.json  :

```
[
 {
   "id": 2900000,
   "name": "Randu",
   "admin_area": "lomu",
   "country": "Portugal"
 },
 {
   "id": 2900001,
    "name": "Randu",
   "admin_area": "lomu",
   "country": "Portugal"
 },
 {
   "id": 2900002,
    "name": "Randu",
   "admin_area": "lomu",
   "country": "Portugal"
 },
 {
   "id": 2900003,
    "name": "Isis",
   "admin_area": "lomu",
   "country": "Portugal"
 },
 {
    "name": "Randu",
   "admin_area": "lomu",
   "country": "Portugal"
 },
 {
   "id": 2900005,
   "name": "Satimola",
   "admin_area": "Thuringen",
   "country": "Taiwan"
 },
...
```

NewData.json :

```
[
  {
    "id": 13610,
    "name": "Satimola",
    "admin_area": "USA"
  },
  {
    "id": 4129,
    "name": "Isis",
    "admin_area": "UK"
  },
  {
    "id": 14698,
    "name": "Reban",
    "admin_area": "Russia"
  },
  {
    "id": 8194,
    "name": "Randu",
    "admin_area": "USA"
  },
  {
    "id": 18867,
    "name": "Randu",
    "admin_area": "USA"
  },
...
```

Comment: Can you share some example of OldData.json?

Comment: Yes of course, I added it to my post

Comment: what is common between old and new data?

Comment: Thx, can't figure out how are you trying to show the data on the table... 
I imagine that with 4 columns `name, country, etc` and instead you are just trying to render all in one cell, very confusing.

Comment: The name value name is common to old and new data. Should I OldData.push() my data ?

Comment: So for instance in olddata you have a name that is `Randu` does that mean only one name in new data matches this name? how do you want to display multiple past searches? Maybe it would be good to post the new data as well :)

Comment: Can you show a bit _more_ code? The code you're showing seems to be using variables that aren't declared anywhere else. Also, your constructor really wants to be `constructor(props) { super(props); ... }` because you're writing a React component.

Comment: I edited my post to show that there is more than one name in common  between both of  Json files.

Comment: So how do you want that to be displayed? if the names are the same and the name is what is an old / recent search then you just see the same name side by side but one is in an input? something doesn't make sense here

Comment: I added all my import to my post. I want my input to suggest me a name from the OldTable when I am starting to type something inside it. I think I need to put all the name of the OldTable in const RecentSearches.

Comment: you're rendering an input for every row. Do you want each of them to search all old data? this sounds like a really weird thing to do. Why not just one input to do your searching and filtering?

Comment: To be honest I tought it will be easier to do it like that. But yes it is not necessary.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I need this constructor to execute my pagination.js

Comment: No, the constructor is called _by React_ when you use `<NewDataTable...>` and you _need_ to include `props` as constructor argument, falling through to `super(props)`, if you want _anything that you pass as a prop_ to actually work. It might be worth retaking https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html to refamiliarise yourself with the way React needs to you structure code (or to catch up on how it's changed since you started using React).